# Inner workings of .NET – can be built-in settings loader reached by code?

Tags: .net, startup, application-settings, my.settings

I joined a project where .NET Windows Forms application is using [Settings mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (**Project** > **Properties** > **Settings**) to preserve both user settings and application settings. I have created command-line tool which uses `LoadAssembly(<main application EXE file>)` to perform some functionalities of main app. Upon invoking of main app's methods everything works fine **except when comes to Settings** – of course, because they were not loaded – settings loader was skipped.

But the application heavily relies on settings so I need to call that settings loader explicitly. But I can't find it: I have analyzed all files of blank .NET project with **Settings** added and loading routine is nowhere to find.

I think at worst I can workaround the problem and implement

- locating settings file
- explicit loading of its content

but I do not like re-inventing the wheel and especially I don't like non-transparent handling of loading of settings on .NET platform.
**Is there any way to invoke built-in code used by .NET framework to load `My.Settings` on application start-up?**

**Note:** Application is written in VB.NET but I think for C# the thing is the same, so do not hesitate to present C# way of thinking, if you want to.

Comment: If this is the settings presented as part of the project properties tab, then [this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961929/load-project-settings-from-net-assembly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently found, that default way how settings are handled **does not allow nor even support my scenario.** Evaluation of

`ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal).FilePath`

gives **different local settings directory** when invoked from original application and when invoked from loaded assembly. Compare outputs of the same method:

When called directly:

`C:\Users\Miroxlav\AppData\Local\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplicationSetting_Url_za1afclumj0mqqjsghdpysdumjr5jd21\1.0.0.0\user.config`

When called as part of loaded assembly invoked from another app:

`C:\Users\Miroxlav\AppData\Local\WindowsApplication1\TestWindowsApplicationSet_Url_cxikfslvgbja50yw4lvnvugko41ou5jz\1.0.0.0\user.config`

So with **default settings provider** even location of config file cannot be determined directly. 
**This basically renders void all potential subsequent steps of direct retrieval of My.Settings of loaded assembly** (without helper files, additional workarounds utilizing fixed settings etc. – while keeping default settings provider)

The way out can be to write [custom settings provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746933/how-do-i-supply-extra-info-to-iapplicationsettingsprovider-class) which stores settings at universally accessible location although it is much greater overhead than I expected I will find.

**Update:** As a quick workaround I have implemented helper file to save config location on start of the main application. When main application's code is launched as loaded assembly, I'm [restoring **My.Settings** from the config file](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/381700/Loading-settings-from-config-file) found at location saved in helper file.

Answer (score -1):

System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration
   (ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

Comment: I'm playing with this but it still looks like a small step on a longer way to go. It actually addresses part of first point (*locate settings file*) of **workaround** I proposed. As far as I undestand, the result needs to be converted to configuration file, its sections should be checked read and the all content then needs to be transferred to `My.Settings` by sort of shallow copy. In this state I cannot accept or upvote this as an answer. (1) It is indirect answer. (2) If you can leave some experience or information rather than this single-liner without any info, I'll appreciate that. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I understand. This has some more detail here |http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049868/how-to-load-config-file-programmatically, and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505566/loading-custom-configuration-files. In terms of preventing the sideways copy override the string accessor this[string propertyName] in the Settings.cs generated by vs.net and get your settings value from whatever source you see fit - the default will get from a configuration file stream, but you can override and supply from any source.

Comment: – finally I found this cannot be achieved by some trivial trick. Way is to write own settings provider always pointing to the same settings storage (and then handling read/writing of settings).